# Updating the data in the current cell

Tags: date, google-sheets

Can anyone help me in the below execution : I need past current date in current cell with saving all my changes. For example, i typed 'bla bla' in current cell and after unfocus it i want to see 18.03.21 - bla bla Is it possible in Google Sheets?
And one more important thigs. I need set date a a text cause TODAY() constructions is updating everytime when tables is reloading or updating
Thanks all and sorry for my eng

Comment: @Ashgabat - only English on this site. There is another SO for russian-onlly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var date = String(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Europe/Moscow', 'dd.MM.yy'));
  var range = e.range;
  range.setValue(e.value + " - " + date);
}
```

[formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: On first look it's work fine. But if i manually update values into cell i see here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pORDjJWU8bFFSEjUaYd98SwzGTiRn3Yw/view and deleted is broken

Comment: "For example, i typed 'bla bla' in current cell and after unfocus it i want to see 18.03.21 - bla bla"


Do you mean that after unfocusing, not "18.03.21 - bla bla" appears on the sheet, but "bla bla - 18.03.21"?
This is easy to fix, just swap the elements in the range.setValue () formula, like this: `range.setValue (date + "-" + e.value)`

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [accepted-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)